# Draw Bar char with Android SQLite data in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, bar-chart

I want draw a Bar chart by using Android based on Android SQLite database data. please send any useful links or samples to me so that I can get some idea I am very new to Data Analytics in Android.

Comment: Hey take a look at this post it may may be helpful to you http://developer.aiwgame.com/canvas-draw-bar-charts-and-pie-charts-in-android.html

Comment: how can i plot graph with Sqllite data base values ?

Comment: @user1581368 In that post he is using specific to draw chart values and you have to use values from the database.For that you should know how to use database in android for that take a look at this post http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you need this...

```
- AFreeChart is a free charting library for Android(tm) platform.

- AFreeChart is based on JFreeChart 1.0.13.
```

amazingly easy to use... demos are readily available...
you can get it from [here](http://code.google.com/p/afreechart/)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If it's OK to send the data to a server & assume an internet connection then I think the best solution on Android is to use the [Google Chart Tools](https://developers.google.com/chart/).

Comment: i want write the code for fetch data from sqllite and display chart?

Comment: The data source is not relevant. I would suggest you read up on how to use SQLite database in Android and then re-address the "how can I display this information?" question based on your requirements.

Comment: Downvoter... Follow protocol and add a comment. Also, look at the time of this answer. There are certainly better tools theses days 3.5 years later.

Answer (score -1):

I used [AChartEngine](http://www.achartengine.org/content/demo.html) for rendering bar charts using data from SQLite. Actually the source of your data is immaterial. Once you query your data from SQLite, you can populate the chart using the chart engine's API.

Compared to AFreeChart, which is distributed under the LGPL, AChartEngine is released under the more permissible Apache 2.0 license.

[image]

Comment: when i download and run the source it closes to debug mode where i am doing changes ?

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.achartengine.model.XYMultipleSeriesDataset

Comment: i got the above error when i am running the app?

Comment: You'll have to export the achartengine jar when building the APK. Tick the check mark for achartengine-1.0.0.jar in Java Build Path in Project Properties.